# Kiosk auto refresh

Tags: raspbian-jessie, kiosk

I have my Pi3 running Jessie 8 set to boot Chromium into Kiosk mode calling a web published Google slide show and it works correctly as it did with Wheezy.  The next step is to refresh the web page every 15 minutes to load any changes that have been made to the slide show.  In the past I added a cronjob to call a script which used xdotool to execute "Ctrl+F5" keys. I have the cronjob running and it will call the refresh.sh file but it will not send the key command for refresh.

My refresh.sh file code is attached below

```
 #refresh chromium 
export DISPLAY=:0.0
xdotool key "ctrl+F5"
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the easiest solution would be to install [an auto refresh extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-refresh/ifooldnmmcmlbdennkpdnlnbgbmfalko) in chromium itself.

Alternatively, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977168/bookmarklet-to-refresh-page-every-minute-or-so-so-i-dont-lose-session-data-whi) suggests the following JS code to reload current page every 15 minutes:

```
javascript:_x=setInterval(function(){open(location.href, 'otherWindow')}, 1000*60*15)
```

Copy this code into your address bar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. To stop refreshing, close the tab and open it again.

Comment: I have tried many different extensions and they require user intervention to start them and that is not an option.  This kiosk needs to boot to the published google slide show and refresh without anyone touching the Pi.  There will be many of these kiosks setup and to connect to each one every day would take far to long.

Comment: @ecmeccjon Then I presume you save the URL of your site in browser preferences as the homepage? Try saving the JS as the home page instead, replacing `location.href` with the site URL.

Comment: @ecmeccjon did you solve your problem? how?

Answer (score 1):

> I have the cronjob running and it will call the refresh.sh file but it will not send the key command for refresh.

Since this is a kiosk, a better idea would be to include something like this in your `.xinit`:

```
(
    sleep 900
    xdotool key "ctrl+F5"
) &
```

Before the chromium invocation.